# Send list of vector2 to php

Tags: c#, php, list, unity-game-engine

I need to send a list of Vector2 from Unity3d to a php page.
Unfortunately I don't how to do this correctly.

I got this code:

```
public void SaveTappedPositions(List<Vector2> tappedPositions)
{
    WWW url = new WWW(SAVE_TAPPED_POSITIONS_URL + UDID + "&tappedPositions=" + tappedPositions);
    StartCoroutine(SendRequest(url));
}
```

Well it get send succesfully, but the url is this

```
http://www.url.com?deviceId=260e3a51d6339640503c04ca06d5b63c3ffc282c&
    tappedPositions=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.Vector2]
```

Which is not good ofcourse. I need all the Vector2 in some kind of long string (atleast something PHP can handle) and then send it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nedd to send a string,not a list.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string aa in tappedPositions) { sb.Append(aa + ";"); }//i used ; for separetato,is your choice.
```

Then send via:

```
WWW url = new WWW(SAVE_TAPPED_POSITIONS_URL + UDID + "&tappedPositions=" + sb);
```